# How to get file from custom named mongoDB gridfs chat_upload.files using c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, gridfs

I'm trying to fetch a file from custom named gridFs using C#?
By default C# code searches the file in fs.files.

Comment: [From the documentation:](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/gridfs/gettingstarted/) *The BucketName value is the root part of the files and chunks collection names, so in this example the two collections would be named “videos.files” and “videos.chunks” instead of “fs.files” and “fs.chunks”.* And there is even example config usage.

Comment: Is gridFs and bucket are same.?

Comment: Look at the link. That's the blue thing there.